# Filter by exact numeric value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.table which I want to filter to find only rows of data where `fresh_flow==0.187677777777778`.

```
df<-data.table::as.data.table(fresh_flow=as.numeric(rep(c(0.59347556, 0.05940667, 0.18767778, 1.87677778, 0.01876778),each=1e2)))

df%>%
dplyr::filter(fresh_flow==0.187677777777778)
```

Returns a result as expected. With my data it returns an empty table even though the column type is also numeric and contains the same unique values. Why?

```
df$fres_flow %>% str()
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fresh_flow: num  0.188 0.188 0.188 0.188 0.188 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

    MyData$fresh_flow %>% str()
     num [1:10499995] 0.5935 0.5935 0.0594 0.0594 0.0594
 
unique(MyData$fresh_flow)
    [1] 0.59347556 0.05940667 0.18767778 1.87677778 0.01876778
```

Comment: `0.01876778` & `0.187677777777778` are not exactly the same, are they?

Comment: Computers have limitations when it comes to floating-point numbers (aka `double`, `numeric`, `float`). This is a fundamental limitation of computers in general, in how they deal with non-integer numbers. This is not specific to any one programming language. There are some add-on libraries or packages that are much better at arbitrary-precision math, but I believe most main-stream languages (this is relative/subjective, I admit) do not use these by default. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518, https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: If you want to find that number, you need to look for numbers that are close *with tolerance*, such as `abs(fresh_flow - 0.187677778) < 1e-13` or similar.

Comment: That is true. How could you build into this a rounding such that it doesn't matter which value you choose as long as the first three digits were the same without altering the data?

Comment: @r2evans thank you that makes sense. How would you put that inequality into the filter function?

Comment: Just wrap it? `dplyr::filter(abs(a-b)<d)`